# How does Google Earth Engine deal with scaling up/down categorical data?

Tags: google-earth-engine, resolution, resampling

I read the docs on [Resampling and Reducing Resolution](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/resample) and [Projections](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections). I sort of get that the scale/projection is determined by the final outcome but I still don't get how categorical data are handled. The Resampling and Reducing Resolution post mentions nearest neighbour, bilinear, bicubic, weighted pixels. But I thought bilinear, bicubic, weighted pixels only works for numerical data. As for nearest neighbour, the doc doesn't give much info on how it is done (It points to the Projection doc, but the Projection doc didn't mention anything about it).

So how are the new pixels handled?

Does a reprojected pixel take on the value of nearest pixel from the original layer or does it take on the weighted mode value of all the original pixels it touches or maybe something else?

Comment: You can resample as you wish, but if your data is categorical, you had better wish to use nearest-neighbor. I found there were situations where is was better to oversample *before* reprojecting (1:25 expansion (5x5) improved annotation quality after nearest resampling; even 3x3 or 4x4 would help, and the increased size was negated by compression)

Comment: The docs on scale give a bit more info on the whole pyramiding processing flow earth engine is using: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/scale

Comment: @JonasV I think your comment is almost the answer! (assuming "discrete" corresponds to categorical in "For discrete valued images, pixel values of upper levels of the pyramid are a sample (usually the top left pixel) of pixels at the next lower level". If you also know how they handle increasing resolution, can you please post it as the full answer?